# Can't get emulator to work in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed the tools I needed in the SDK manager but when I create a new AVD I can't get it to run. [image]

I'm very new to android. Any ideas on what I need to do to get the emulator to run on my computer?

Comment: Have you tried launching them when you run an app? Do you get any errors? you Nexus S won't run as it has no android version or target version set. Try using the default AVDs to start with.

Comment: We might need more details Michael, is there any error message? Are you running on Windows? Linux? Anyhow, I would just recommend you to switch to Genymotion, it is way way faster and easier to set up than the built-in emulator (and it's free for individuals): https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Check the path of your android-sdk on AS settings, do you have installer android 23?

Comment: @g2o he said he had installed the tools he needed in the sdk manager. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I'm asking because right now i have two device with Android 5.0 created in my sdk manager with the same problem and the reason is because i've only android-sdk with platform 23

Comment: @g2o android 5.0 is not the same as sdk 23, 23 is android 6.0, 5.0 is 21

Comment: Well my point is that I've two separated android-sdk folder, one with platform 22 and another with platform 23 created, the Android 5.0 device was created with AS pointing to android-sdk 22, then change AS to point to android-sdk with platform 23 and i've the same problem of @Michael Harvey

Comment: @g2o Unless I am completely misunderstanding you; android studio itself doesn't point to any particular sdk version. You can point an app you are making to whichever api level you choose and you can set up AVDs for any sdk you have installed, but as far as I know android studio itself is pretty universal in regard to sdk/api levels as long as you have the correct toolsets installed.

Comment: Thank you everyone!!! I got the emulator to start but now it just has the android logo. I've been waiting 15 minutes but the android device home screen isn't loading. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: patience... sometimes the first avd startup can take a long time, but fifteen minutes sounds a little extreme. Are you running it on a computer with a decent processor? also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator?rq=1 about that subject

Comment: I'm now getting this error. I'm using a macbook with 4gb ram. "The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration."

Comment: I ended up using genymotion and it works great!